Cannot connect to WiFi or access settings after data wipe
After the factory reset on OnePlus Nord, the screen says, Hello, then connecting to WiFi, and it states it cannot connect.
I cannot access my settings. I cannot do anything with this phone as I cannot get past the "Cannot Connect to WiFi" message.

Make sure your Wifi has no MAC-filter active.
